# Copy table form MS-SQL server to MySQL, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, php

I have a procedure, say "proc1", inside a MS-SQL server.
I would like to create a table (copy of proc1) inside a MySQL server.

So far what I do is this:

```
1-Create a connection to MS-SQL Server
2- run the code $sql = "exec [procedureName] '$param' ";
3-Traverse all 500.000 lines.
4-Store all lines inside a php variable (had to set ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');).
5-Close the connection.
6-Store the data inside a file.
7-Create a table inside a Mysql server, says MySQL_tbl1.
8-Traverse the file, line by line, Sanitize each field -> escape special character and insert inside MySQL_tl1.
Note: I've tried some variations like insert in one shoot. It improve my code only in 10 seconds.
```

If I was dealing with a MySQL table to generate another table inside MySQL I could use [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html). . I think this could be the faster way to create a new table inside the MySQL server.
But I am dealing MS-SQL to MySQL.
So my question is that:
Is it possible to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` in this situation? If yes, how?

Just add a note:
I would like to do this using code => (php+Mysql)

Comment: You could check the instructions at this site: http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/

Comment: Hi RFL, so that means we can do this using code?

Comment: You can do this using code, ETL tools, copy to csv using native tools. It's certainly possible, You are not the first person ever attempting this so google should be of help.

Comment: Why do you want to use (php-MySQL)?  If there is a process you can use successfully, just use it.

Comment: Workbench replaces most of the code in your 8-step list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple... MySQL WorkBench!  Enables migrations from the following systems.

SQL Server, Access, PostgreSQL, SyBase, etc...
Manage migration projects
Source & Target selection
Object migration
Version upgrades

Here's the link... http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/

Price is good too! ;-)

-Tony